# how to take away all the spaces and punctuation in a string? (python)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, ide

```
def pre_process(t):
    """ (str) -> str
    returns a copy of the string with all punctuation removed, and all letters set to lowercase. The only characters in the output will be lowercase letters, numbers, and whitespace.

    """
```

Comment: What you tried? Did you googled? If you would have, you would have got the answer as first link

Comment: Check the [Google Search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20remove%20all%20spaces%20and%20punctuation%20from%20the%20string) result

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest function using `regex` I could put together to achieve your requirement.

```
import re
def pre_process(t):
    return re.sub(r'[^a-z\d ]','',str.lower())
```

It will return the input string in lower case, and omit any characters that are not *letters*, *numbers* or *whitespace*.

Comment: thank you! works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
import re

string = 'This is an example sentence.'
string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d]', string)

print(string)
```

You should get out `Thisisanexamplesentance`.

Comment: what about "123 !@ Test" ?

Comment: Well observed! I've put numbers in there as well, I assume that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild your string with only alpha-numeric characters:

```
''.join(_char for _char in _str.lower() if _char.isalnum())
```